# Complex inverse function for power

Tags: complex-numbers, inverse-function

I am note sure about an exercise which asks to find a right inverse function of $w=z^3$

May I simply answer that is
$z=\sqrt[3]{|w|}(\cos\frac{\theta+2k\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{\theta+2k\pi}{3})$?

In the same question, I have to find a right inverse function g for $w=z^4$ such that $g(-1)=\frac{\sqrt(2)(1+i)}{2}$... I know that If I choose $k=0$ and $\theta =\pi$ in the n-th root formula, I reach that condition. So, should the answer be $g(w)=\sqrt[4]{|w|}(\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{4})$?

Comment: What domain are you trying to find the inverse on? $w = z^n$ is not invertible on $\mathbb{C}$ if $n > 1$.

Comment: From $\mathbb{C}$ to$\mathbb{C}$... Edit.. I need to find a right inverse

Comment: What's right inverse?

Comment: $g:B\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is a right inverse of $f:B\rightarrow A$ of $f$ in $B$, $B\subset f(A) $ if $f(g(w)) =w$, $\forall w\in B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers are on the right track. For the $z^3$ problem you need to specify that $\theta = \operatorname{Arg}(w)$, and state what $k$ is (an arbitrary integer in your case). For $z^4$ you can't just take $\theta = \pi$ because $\theta = \operatorname{Arg}(w)$ varies with $w$. (The $g(w)$ you wrote has $g(w)^4 = -|w|$ which is not what you want). You can use a similar approach to what you did on $z^3$ be defining $$
g(w) = \sqrt[4]{|w|} \left(\cos\left(\frac{\operatorname{Arg}(w) + 2 k \pi}{4}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{\operatorname{Arg}(w) + 2 k \pi}{4}\right)\right)
$$
Then you need to determine what value of $k$ will have $g(-1) = \frac{\sqrt2}2(1 + i)$

Comment: So starting from $g(-1)= \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i)$, I have $\sqrt[4]{|-1|}\left(\cos\frac{\pi+2k\pi}{4}+\cdots\right)= \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i)$  which means $\frac{\pi+2k\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{4} +2n\pi$, $n$ integer and, with some simplification, $k=4n$....is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: What a relief.!

Answer (score 1):

You can find a "Cartesian" formula for the fourth root.

Let $z^2=(u+iv)^2=x+iy$. By identification,

$$u^2-v^2=x,\\2uv=y$$

so that

$$(u^2-v^2)^2+4u^2v^2=(u^2+v^2)^2=x^2+y^2$$

and the positive solutions are

$$u^2=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}2,\\v^2=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x}2.$$

So we have established

$$\sqrt{x+iy}=\pm\frac12\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}+i\sqrt{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x}\right)$$

and it suffices to iterate to get

$$\sqrt{\sqrt{x+iy}}=
\\\pm\frac12\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)}\pm\frac12\sqrt{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}}+i\sqrt{\sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)}\mp\frac12\sqrt{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}}\right).$$

Note that the inner $\pm\,\mp$ are "synchronized" and there are four solutions.